# How to kill all child threads

Tags: pthreads

I have a C++ program and use pthreads in it. In this program the threads are used to search for a pattern in the data. Here is how I'm doing it in my program:

```
for (i=0; i<NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    assert(0==rc);
    if (args[i].islast == true || args[i].nextaddr != NULL){ //if the pattern is found
        for (j = i+1; j<NUM_THREADS;j++){
            rc = pthread_join(threads[j], NULL); //join the other threads that is not useful
            assert(0 == rc);
        }
        return args[i].nextaddr; //return the address obtained in the thread of interest
    }
}
```

But this second `for`-loop to join the threads that are not useful is costly (the program needs to be very fast, and if I can avoid a simple "for" it's a great achievement).

I want to know if there exists any command that I can kill all child threads at once.

P.s: I need to "join" the useless threads. If I don't do this, that threads can't be recycled and after a time I reach the limit of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for-loop in order to join various threads, you can use
barriers.

```
pthread_barrier_t barrier; // the barrier object
pthread_t threads [NUM_THREADS]; // the thread childs.

// create the threads ...

// initialize the barrier like other pthread object.
pthread_barrier_init (&barrier, NULL, NUM_THREADS+1);
```

note that the 2nd parameter are the attributes of the barrier. if NULL, default attributes
will be set. the 3rd argument is the number of threads that will be syncronized by the
barrier. Each thread will call to pthread_barrier_wait to wait for the other threads that will call to the same function as well. when a specific number of threads are 
waiting in the barrier, all threads will be unblocked.

I wrote NUM_THREADS+1, NUM_THREADS is the number of child threads, and increment it to 
count as well the main thread.

in the "important thread", you can write something like this to wait for the child threads.

```
/* do important stuff while child threads are executing ... */

/* wait for the childs (join) */
pthread_barrier_wait (&barrier); // main thread gets blocked by the barrier.
                               // untill a specific number of threads reaches the
                               // barrier as well

/* continue execution ... */
```

in the child threads, add the next line of code ...

```
void* child_thread_func (void* args)
{
    /* do something with the thread ... */

    /* syncronize with the barrier and exit */
    pthread_barrier_wait (&barrier);

    pthread_exit (some_data);
}
```

by this way, when the child will be unblocked, it inmediatly returns and joins with the main thread.

don´t forget to free the resources associated with the barrier.
(only if any thread no longer use the barrier) ...

```
pthread_barrier_destroy (&barrier);
```